# Synchronize content in Umbraco

Tags: .net, umbraco

Is there any good tool to synchronize content / dictionary items within the Umbraco CMS through different environments, besides [Courier](http://umbraco.com/products/more-add-ons/courier-2.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. Dictionary items can be synced using uSync, which will also sync DocTypes, DataTypes and Templates etc: [here's the project page](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/usync) uSync is pretty stable and is a great way to sync structural changes to your site.

Content is more problematic, the only non-Courier option I've seen is uSync content edition: [here;s the project page](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/usynccontentedition) the main issue is that it's only experimental, and only really works with fairly simple site structures.

Of the two, I've used uSync extensively, and it's been good. I've experimented with uSync content edition, but it was too flaky for me to want to risk using it on sizable production sites.

Comment: Is there anything new coming out in 7.2 or higher?

Comment: In this last week's uHangout, Per mentioned that Courier is being upgraded for 7, but it'll still be paid for. Copying content in Umbraco is a lot trickier than you'd think, because everythiung has numeric id's which aren't very portable between different environments.